# Error trying to run a python program

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

Hello guys I'm actually new to Terminal and Python. Just started following a Python tuturial on my Ubuntu and I've reached a part where it asks me to save a .py file and open it in Terminal.

Only when I try to type on Terminal $ python egotrip.py I get $: command not found
Then I try to type it in python and I get

```
File "", line 1
    python egotrip.py
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I mean all names are correct :(

Then I gave also tried `/home/anacah/Desktop/python/egotrip.py`
And I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'home' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? :(  can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this line in the terminal:
`python /home/anacah/Desktop/python/egotrip.py`

thereby providing the entire path for the file including the `/` at the beginning, and see what happens.  If it errors out, please edit your initial post with the section 'Additional Information' and paste the error message.

Comment: No way lol  thanks a lot to take the time to help a rookie go 'round :)

Comment: @Ana, no problem.  Note that two things should be considered when running a .py program: (1) where the file is located, (2) where your current 'working directory' is (you can find that with `pwd`), and (3) whether you are *in* the directory the file is located in.  If you put the full path, like I stated, it should work correctly, but to do the full path, you need to have the initial `/`, stating "Start at the root of the drive, then use <rest of path> to find the file".

Answer (score 2):

Change directories to the folder where your `.py` file is stored.  Your command should look like this:

```
cd /home/anacah/Desktop/python
```

From your information above, it looks as if you left out the `cd` command.  Once in that folder, just type:

```
python egotrip.py
```

and it should work!